# How To Match String Containing Comma In MySQL

Tags: mysql, match, against

Our DB contains a lot of entries with comma in their titles (as in Hungarian, it's the decimal separator instead of period) and would like to match those with the right relevance. The search SQL looks like this currently in case of the user inputted terms are **7,5x20 otherTerm**

```
SELECT (MATCH(title) AGAINST('(+7,5x20* +otherTerm* ) (7,5x20* otherTerm* ) (+7,5x20 +otherTerm )' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AS Relevance,
id, title, product_id FROM versions

WHERE (MATCH(title) AGAINST('(+7,5x20* +otherTerm* ) (7,5x20* otherTerm* ) (+7,5x20 +otherTerm )' IN BOOLEAN MODE))

ORDER BY Relevance DESC LIMIT 50
```

Now the result order gives a higher relevance for eg. **5x20** than **7,5x20** so there has to be some kind of character escaping has to be done on the comma, preventing MySQL to handle them as separated strings. I didn't find the right one.

Thanks for any help in advance.

**Edit:** disassembling title into more digestible data is currently not an option. Really looking for solution escaping the comma or replacing it with 'match any single character' operator like dot in regex.

Comment: Consider not storing delimited data, if you then want to query against that data.

Comment: To maybe make Strawberry's comment a little more useful, when you store a number, store it as a number. I don't have a good feel for your schema here, but I think you will ne well-served to decompose your data to its root values and say goodbye to the quirks of the natural language matching.

Comment: Thanks @Jerry (and @Strawberry), fair point, and maybe the example is wrong because contains all numeric values. It's the most common occurence of this problem in our case, however I think there has to be a way to incorporate strings with comma to use. Would be the best solution to disassemble those titles to properties, however it would be overkill for us now.

Comment: Honestly, I think the example is a good one, because it shows you are trying to cram too much information into a single database field. You have a big string that contains a lot of information. You need to break that information down and describe it with your database table definitions. One you do that, the sun will rise, the birds will begin to sing, and you will suddenly feel the power of controlling your information.

Comment: @Jerry couln't agree more, however it's not an option this time. Herited DB with 50k entries in this table, belonging to several different categories with different (and observed or not) naming convetions... needs crazy amount of TLC from somebody. This somebody won't be me. ;)
So I really just would like to escape the comma, or change it to a 'one character' operator like dot in regex.

Comment: You can use `REGEXP`

Comment: @aRvi if you have the time, could you make an answer for the bounty?

Comment: The fact that the comma is in a number is a red herring. If I understand, you want it to match the phrase "I think, therefore I am" with a higher relevance for "I think, therefore I am" than with "I think therefore I am". But the MATCH operator ignores non-word characters.  You should be able to do this by a REPLACE inside the MATCH syntax, eg MATCH(REPLACE(title , "," , "Q") AGAINST('("*7Q5x20* +otherTerm* )...

Comment: @Morten I really like the approach as it doesn't need an extra db field, however i didn't have luck putting anything in MATCH except field name. SELECT ( MATCH ( REPLACE(title,",","Q") ) AGAINST => You have an error in your SQL syntax; or SELECT REPLACE(title,",","_") as modtitle, ( MATCH ( modtitle ) AGAINST... => Unknown column 'modtitle' in 'field list

Comment: Indeed - looks like the MATCH operator is unable to accept previously aliased fields as input, and with using anything other than a field name as input. So to use that method you're back to creating an intermediate view with the replaced results and then run the match on that view.

Answer (score 0):

`FULLTEXT` indexing is not designed to handle numbers, regardless of the Locale for the numbers.

One approach is to alter the incoming text to replace punctuation that you want to treat as "letters" into, say, `_`.  (And build a separate column for storing this altered text into.  Then add the `FULLTEXT` index to it instead of the "real" text.)

Please note that `+x` will fail in a bad way -- one character strings are not indexed, so they cannot be found.  So including strings that are two short leads to returning zero matches.

Alterations to the saved text (eg, `7_5x20`) needs to be applied to the search, too.

50K rows?  Write a special, one-time, script to perform the above transformation to the existing 50K rows.  Then incorporate the transformations into both the INSERTs and the SELECTs.